# Can I enter Chile just before my visa expires? Indian citizen

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, chile, tourist-visas

Chile tourist visa is issued on May 26th. It says "Duration of 30 days // To be used within 90 days of issue".

Can I enter Chile on August 22nd (89th day) and stay for 2 weeks?

I went to a Chilean Embassy to confirm this. The front desk assistant took my case in writing and later called me to say "It is fine as long as I enter Chile before expiry".

Still I am tensed because this is an immigration issue. I am on an Indian passport.

Comment: Given that one is allowed to answer one's own question, should this be closed, or edited to move the answer out of the question? It seems like a valid question otherwise.

Comment: I am looking to know if anybody has similar experience. If i should get a letter in writing from the consulate.

Comment: Did they say anything about when you have leave? I don't think many people to this type of travel. Most get a new visa.

Comment: No.  Because maximum stay of 30 days from the day of entry may not cover stay beyond visa validity period.  In the US such travel is possible in other countries it is not.  Question still remains what is the exit requirement?  T+30 or because visa exprires on T+1 it could be T+1

Comment: @Karlson They have not told me anything on when to leave. All i got is a vm from the front desk assistant, i did not get that in writing either.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, the answer that the OP got was not very _authoritative_, and it happened to me multiple times in Chile that what one _front desk assistant_ said was completely wrong and it caused me much trouble and stress afterwards.

Comment: @pnuts Which doesn't contradict anything.  Yes you can enter but do you have to leave on the 90th day?  I don't know the answer.  Do you?

Comment: @pnuts That was the question but not the question the embassy.

Comment: I again called Embassy to actually talk to a counsellor who gave me the visa. He told me the following "You have 90 days to use the visa. Then another 30 days to stay inside Chile. (But he also suggested me that usually if i enter around 89th/90th day, they may not stamp me for 30 days, but might give me 20 days at a manimum).

Comment: @pnuts There is no one right or wrong answer here and i believe this should not be treated like other forums of stack exchange. In my opinion if even 1 in million goes through similar situation and shares his experience by seeing this question - i can be more peaceful and stress free.

Comment: What passport are you on? Lots of countries usually get 90 day visas for Chile, so I'm curious.

Comment: Indian passport. Yup - not so easy like US or some other countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I agree with what the 'front desk' told you.

The Chilean visitor visa system works like this...

You get a period of validity, in your case 30 days.  We can call this 'unspent leave'.  You get a period in which to report to Chile and present your credentials.  In your case, and in most cases, 90 days from the issue date.

Your 'unspent leave' is fully intact on your arrival date as long as you enter the country before the 90 days is finished.  It decreases by one day for each day that you are in the country.

**Can I enter Chile on August 22nd (89th day) and stay for 2 weeks?**

Yes, the 'clock' on your 30 days will begin ticking on 22 August.  Once you have entered Chile, the 90 days has no further meaning and you can remain beyond that date as long as you continue to have 'unspent leave'.

Also note that you can extend a visitor visa after your arrival in Chile as long as the result conforms to { spent leave + unspent leave <= 90 } and you meet the other qualifications.  In your case, it means you *might* be able to qualify for a 60 day extension from within Chile.

Also note that generally speaking the 'front desk' is not always reliable because that type of staff is not trained in the consulting skills needed to get a clear understanding of your question.  So they may not pass it on correctly.  For technical questions about visas, the minimum rank you can rely upon is Vice Consul, otherwise you may be wasting your time.

Source: Vice Consul, Visa Section (name redacted), Consulado General de Chile en Londres, 26 Aug 2015

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I entered Chile last saturday. The immigration was the shortest i had ever faced in 5-6 countries. The immigration lady who spoke very little english asked me the following question in an astonished tone "Did you get your in May? .....In May..!!!???" - I firmly said a yes - without more questions or re-examing my passport she stamped and let me go.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering my own question]

I entered Chile on the 89th day without any issues. The immigration officer gave me an surprised look about the issue. But she stamped me for 20 days as was pointed out by the embassy official.

So Chile's visa is like 90 days to enter and another 2-4 weeks to stay.

Answer (score -2):

I have a similar situation. I am Indian and I have a simple tourism Chilean visa. It says that my visa has 90 days validity from 13th oct 2016. For some reason I have to travel and enter into Chile on Jan 7th. Does it mean that my stay's validity start from Jan 7th?